# Running Totals again. No over clause, no cursor, but increasing order

Tags: sql

I am still having trouble creating an running total based on the increasing order of the value. Row id has no real meaning, it is just the PK. My server doesn't support OVER.

```
Row Value
1 3
2 7
3 1
4 2
```

Result:

```
Row Value
3 1
4 3
1 6
2 13
```

I have tried self and cross joins where I specify that the value of the second amount(the one being summed up) is less than the current value of the first. I have also tried doing this with the having clause but that always threw an error when I tried it that way. Can someone explain why it would be wrong to use it in that manner and how I should be doing it?

Comment: It would help if you told us what your server is, rather than what it doesn't support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do a running total:

```
select row, value,
       (select sum(value) from t t2 where t2.value <= t.value) as runningTotal
from t
```

Comment: The self-join with inequality (aka triangular join) is one of the worst-performing ways to get running totals, but given the restrictions imposed by the question it looks like the only remaining choice.

Comment: @Simon . . . Yes, I too believe that all database vendors should support the full range of window/analytic functions.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the with rollup command if you have sql server 2008.

```
select sum(value) from t t2 where t2.value <= t.value with rollup
```

Comment: `with rollup` is not a new (2008) feature and doesn't do running totals either. It is used in conjunction with `GROUP BY` to give sub totals.

Answer (score 0):

If your platform supports recursive queries(IIRC you should omit the RECURSIVE keyword for microsoft stuff). Because the CTE needs to estimate the begin/end of a "chain", unfortunately, the tuples need to be ordered in some way (I use the "row" field; an internal tuple-id would be perfect for this purpose):

```
WITH RECURSIVE sums AS (
    -- Terminal part
    SELECT  d0.row
    , d0.value AS value
    , d0.value AS runsum
    FROM data d0
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM data nx
        WHERE nx.row < d0.row
        )
    UNION
    -- Recursive part
    SELECT  t1.row AS row
    , t1.value AS value
    , t0.runsum + t1.value AS runsum
    FROM data t1
    , sums t0
    WHERE t1.row > t0.row
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM data nx
        WHERE nx.row > t0.row
        AND nx.row < t1.row
        )
    )
SELECT * FROM sums
    ;
```

RESULT:

```
 row | value | runsum 
-----+-------+--------
   1 |     3 |      3
   2 |     7 |     10
   3 |     1 |     11
   4 |     2 |     13
(4 rows)
```